How to automatically extract last reply text from email MIME?
As you may now, many email clients applies citations about previous emails under reply content.
I want to clean up email string from those citations.
My goal is to develop Go code that from following input string extracts LAST_REPLY_TEXT.
Do you have any ideas how to implement it?
--000000000000c8479a0621de2129
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

LAST_REPLY_TEXT

Wed, 11 sep 2024 at 22:49 John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com> wrote:

> ORIGINAL_TEXT_LINE_1
> ORIGINAL_TEXT_LINE_2
--000000000000c8479a0621de2129


What have you tried so far?  You should tag this go.  Are writing this from scratch or using an existing mime parser?  Edit your question with answers.
